# phonegap vertical plus horizontal scroll with single touch on multple elements

Tags: html, ios, cordova, touch, vertical-scroll

This one is not for the kids at home. I will reward anyone who comes close to a solution. I have included a working example of what i want that u can use to try to fix the problem. This must work in a phonegap application on a iphone/android devices. What i want to do is simple. I want to be able to scroll vertical with the "text elements" i have in the containing div. When i touch the red images to the right then they can scroll horizontally. If i scroll the images sideways thats fine, but if i keep holding down the finger and scroll vertically nothing happens to the text elements. I want to be able to scroll the text elements vertically when i press the image-elements.. Please help me out on this one guys :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style type="text/css">

   #exerciseMenu{

    height:600px;
    overflow:scroll;
   }
.scrollImages{
            width: 100px;
            height: 125px;
            margin:10px 5px;
            float:left;
            background-color:red;

        }
    .headerWrapper{
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: box;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -moz-box-align: center;
            box-align: center;
            width:200px;
            height:157px;

        }
.exerciseWrapper{


    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;

    position:relative;
        border:5px solid black;
        background-color:white;
            height:157px;

        } 
.scrollWrapper {

                position:absolute; 
                border-left:6px solid black;
                right:0px;
                top:0px;
                padding-left:5px;
                width:260px;
                height:148px;
                background:#aaa;

                overflow-x:auto;



            } 
.scroller {
                padding:0;
                width:1000px;


            }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){


 $('body').append('<div id="exerciseMenu"></div>'); 



        for (var i=0;i<8;i++)
            {           
                AppendMenuItems();
            }

        });
       function AppendMenuItems(){

  var menuu=$('#exerciseMenu').append('<div class="exerciseWrapper">TEXT<div class="scrollWrapper"><div class="scroller">'+ 
            '<div class="scrollImages">Im</div>'+
            '<div class="scrollImages">Im</div>'+
            '<div class="scrollImages">Im</div>'+
            '<div class="scrollImages">Im</div>'+
            '<div class="scrollImages">Im</div>'+
            '<div class="scrollImages">Im</div>'+
            '<div class="scrollImages">Im</div>'+
            '<div class="scrollImages">Im</div>'+
            '</div></div></div></div>');


}
    </script>

</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a poorly explained question and it's unclear what the behavior is you're looking for.  I suggest you create a jsFiddle example and maybe some diagrams of what you mean.